# Customized hierarchy output

Tags: sql, oracle

For Oracle SQL 10g/11g

I have three tables as below -

Country

```
ID NAME  
1 United States  
2 England  
3 India
```

City

```
ID NAME  
11 Seattle  
21 Bristol  
31 Mumbai
```

Country_City

```
country_ID city_id  
1 11  
2 21  
3 31
```

Is it possible to get a Hierarchical output in which country and states are distinguishable?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the output that you are looking for.

Comment: -->United States next line -->-->Seattle ......

Answer (score 0):

What if you try like below. See a demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94f19/2

```
select c.NAME as Country,cc.NAME as City
from Country c
inner join country_City c1
on c.ID = c1.country_ID
inner join City cc
on cc.ID = c1.city_id
```

Comment: I have edited the third table in my question. Can you please resend the query as per that....Thanks

Comment: IF you can see the query below, I am trying to add city after a country in the immediate next row - select
level,LPAD('-->',10*LEVEL-1)||c.name
from country c,city ct,country_city cc
where cc.country_id=c.id
and cc.city_id=ct.id
connect by prior ct.id=c.id;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can get the output you want by using `union all`.  The `id` column is used to keep everything within a single country together.  The `ordering` column is used to be sure that the country name is first:

```
select name
from ((select cc.id, c.name, 1 as ordering
       from country_city cc join
            country c
            on cc.countryid = c.id 
      ) union all
      (select cc.id, ci.name, 2 as ordering
       from country_city cc join
            city ci
            on cc.cityid = ci.id 
      )
     ) c
order by id, ordering;
```

Comment: If I run the above it shows - ORA-00904: "C"."ID": invalid identifier

Comment: Can we tweak the below query to have city names after every country name in the next row? - select
level,LPAD('-->',10*LEVEL-1)||c.name
from country c,city ct,country_city cc
where cc.country_id=c.id
and cc.city_id=ct.id
connect by prior ct.id=c.id;

Comment: @user3628424 . . . The query should be putting the country first and then the cities in the country after it.